# Sum of Distincts in Javascript Object using Underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Only just introduced to [_Underscore](http://underscorejs.org) so this may be totally nonsense but I'm wondering if the library can indeed do what I want.

I have an object containing 5 items:

```
Name, v2007,v2008,v2009,v2010
```

I simply want to go through the entire object and get the SUM of each distinct value in `Name` (much similar to SQL's GroupBy and SUM).

I have the following:

```
var distincts = [];
$.each(tmp, function (key, value) {
    $.each(value, function (fieldName, fieldValue) {
        if (fieldName == 'Name') {
            if ($.inArray(fieldValue, distincts) == -1) {
                distincts.push(fieldValue);
            }
        }
    });
});

$.each(distincts, function (a, b) {
    var t = _.where(tmp, {Name: b});
    var sum = _.reduce(t.v2007, function (memo, num) {
        return memo + num;
    }, 0)
    console.log(sum);
});
```

Which is returning 0 all the time, in fact I'm not sure how to retrieve a SUM of fields `v2011`, `v2013` other than hard-coding them in which is simply not practical!

Can someone help me a little here, is there a simple way of getting the _Underscore library to SUM all fields (that, say, start with 'v') based on a Group of the Name?

Comment: Could you show us an example `tmp` object (in JSON format)? Btw, you shouldn't mix Underscore's and jQuery's `each` functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
var groups = _.groupBy(function(name) { return name.charAt(0) });
var sums = _.map(groups, function(group) {
    return _.reduce(group, function (a, b) { return a+b; }, 0);
});
```

Comment: No offense, but shouldn't there be a simpler way to do this with underscore?

Comment: @Jess: I don't think so, Underscore is not a query language but a toolset of some functional helpers. I you find a simpler way, please provide another answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way I came up with that will take an array of objects and return a single object where the "keys" of the object are the grouped value and the "values" of the object are the aggregated value:

```
function groupBy(input, xCol, yCol) {

    var output = {};

    // This function can be easily changed to do max, min, avg, sum.
    var sum = function(row, idx) {
        if (!(row[xCol] in output)) {
            output[row[xCol]] = row[yCol];
        }
        else {
            output[row[xCol]] += row[yCol];         
        }
    };
    _.each(input, sum);

    return output;
}
```

And a test:

```
var input = [ {
    pn : "M1",
    date : "2014-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    qty : 1
}, {
    pn : "M1",
    date : "2014-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    qty : .5
}, {
    pn : "M2",
    date : "2014-01-04T00:00:00Z",
    qty : 2
} ];

it('should group by abc value, showing max.', function() {
    expect(groupBy(input, "pn", "qty")).toEqual({
        "M1" : 1.5,
        "M2" : 2
    });
});
```

This answer only nominally uses underscore for the foreach loop.

Comment: What do you think @Bergi?